# Canvas only shows black screen

Tags: android, tiles

I try to concatenize image tiles into one canvas

here is my code

```
Canvas createCanvas(Bitmap[][] array){

    int height = array[0][0].getHeight();
    int width = array[0][0].getWidth();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(3*height,3*width,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap (array[0][0],0f,0f,new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG));
    canvas.drawBitmap (array[0][1],width,0f,new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
    //etc..etc..for all the tiles

    return canvas;
}
```

invoke this method like this:

```
    //source File
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);
    //Tile Source File
    Bitmap [][] array_ref = helper_ref.createImageArrays(bMap);

    //Invoke Method above
    Canvas canvas = helper_ref.createCanvas(array_ref);
    //Draw canvas 
    ImageView view_ref = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    view_ref.draw(canvas);
```

I also provide you the view in which I want to draw.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you pass null for the last argument in canvas.drawBitmap. Try passing a paint object.

Comment: hmm it didnt work, but it´s a clue. I passed in a default Object new Paint(). Maybe the wrong one?

Comment: I tryed 2 Paint Constants without success, I think that´s not it. I also provide you the view I draw in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look what the [Google docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) say about the method "draw" you call in the last line:

```
void draw(Canvas canvas)
    Manually render this view (and all of its children) to the given Canvas.
```

So the only thing this does is drawing the ImageView (which is empty) to that canvas. So what's actually happening is the opposite of what you want to achieve: You're drawing the ImageView into that bitmap, not the other way round.
The solution is easy: At the end, your method `createCanvas` shouldn't return the the canvas but the bitmap you were drawing to. With the bitmap, do this:
`view_ref.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));`
That should do the trick.